# Java Multi Dimension array -how to read values from spinners

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-spinner

Hello i have 2 drop downs .First drop down[Spinner1] has 4 values  , second[Spinner2]has 5 values.

Now when user selects values from first drop down and another value from second drop down , a
fragment shows up in a part of screen with a webview text.

This is my code

```
import android.R.string;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

public class WebViewerFragment extends Fragment {

    private WebView mWebView;
    // a two dimensional array representing the data to put in the WebView

String SurgEqui="<html><body><h2>Equipment</h2><ul><li><p>IV catheter :Be certain that IV is in place and flushing easily</p></li></body><html>";

     String[][] mData      = new String[4][5]; 




    /*   String [][]mData={{Surg,Surg,Surg,Surg,Surg},{Surg,Surg,Surg,Surg,Surg}
{Surg,Surg,Surg,Surg,Surg}{Surg,Surg,Surg,Surg,Surg}{Surg,Surg,Surg,Surg,Surg}}

  */


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mainView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_layout, container, false);
        mWebView = (WebView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.webView1); 
        return mainView;
    }

    public void updateWebView(int firstSelection, int secondSelection) {
         if (firstSelection == AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION || secondSelection == AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION) {
              return;  
         } else {
              if (mWebView != null) {
                   mWebView.loadData(mData[firstSelection][secondSelection], "text/html", null);
              }
         }

    }


}
```

Now there are 20 html string combinations for these 2 drop downs.How can i use this array for storing and retrieving values.How can i insert 20 HTML strings into array so that i can use
mWebView.loadData(mData[firstSelection][secondSelection], "text/html", null); 
method to read values to display in webview.

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't it be best to just use 2 arrays? or even just 1 array with 20 entries? If you must use your method, what issues are you running into exactly? what you commented out is almost correct:

```
String [][] mData= {
        {Surg,
            Surg,
            Surg,
            Surg,
            Surg},
        {Surg,
            Surg,
            Surg,
            Surg,
            Surg}, //<-- need comma between brackets
        {Surg,
            Surg,
            Surg,
            Surg,
            Surg}, 
        {Surg,
            Surg,
            Surg,
            Surg,
            Surg},
        {Surg,
            Surg,
            Surg,
            Surg,
            Surg}
        }; // <-- don't forget the semicolon
```